# How come its not dynamcally resize based on content?

Tags: html, css

I have this [page](http://dev.posnation.com/build_system/systemconfig.php?id=7&step=1)

and as you can see the text

> - MINI POS PC
> - LENOVO POS PC
> - LENOVO PREMIUM POS PC
> - TABLET PC, PARTNER TECH 10" TOUCH
> - ALL-IN-ONE, POSIFLEX 15" FANLESS
> - ALL-IN-ONE, LENOVO THINKCENTRE 23"

is over the image....how can I make it dynamically dropping the picture based on the number of `li`'s I tried almost everything and I cant get it

Answer (score 0):

The `.dd` div is absolutely positioned, which means that it and it's contents won't interact with any of the other elements on the page. The solution is to remove the following lines from your stylesheet:

```
.printer-nav ul li .dd {
    position:absolute;
}

.printer-nav ul li {
    float:left;
}
```

There are also a lot of other unnecessary styles which can be safely removed to reduce the amount of complexity in your stylesheet.